# Are Areas possible with an all F# website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

Is it possible to have Areas within an all F# MVC 5 website? When I use my F# MVC 5 template, I don't see an option to add an Area, but I'm wondering if there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Have you tried editing the .proj file?  This might be something that isn't supported by the UI right now.

Comment: what should I look for?

Comment: You could start by looking at how the C# .proj file works.

Comment: I tried to replicate the work of the c# area scaffolding. For the area Blog, is needed a folder Areas\Blog, and it's ok. Inside that folder there is common structure ( Models/Views/Controllers) but there is an open bug with nested folders of f# template so can't add Areas\Blog\Controllers ( see https://github.com/fsharp/FSharpCommunityTemplates/issues/78 ).

Comment: @EnricoSada That sounds like an answer to me!